# Where to place is.na() when using grepl to find non-missing non-matches?

Tags: r, dataframe, na, grepl

I want to find those non-missing (!) entries that do not contain a defined expression in var2 and retrieve their respective value of var1. By default, grepl will return also missing entries which I want to avoid. I came up with two approaches and one of them delivers wrong results. I would like to understand **why** it delivers wrong results? Find both the code and the code with output below, please. Thank you!

```
df <- data.frame(
  var1 = 1:150,
  var2 = c(rep(NA, 100), rep("ABC", 45), rep("CBA", 5))
)  

exp <- "BC"

## Correct results with
df$var1[!grepl(exp, df$var2, fixed=T) & !is.na(df$var2)]
# [1] 146 147 148 149 150


## Incorrect results with
df$var1[!grepl(exp, df$var2[!is.na(df$var2)], fixed=T)]
print(df[c(46, 47, 48, 49,  50,  96,  97,  98,  99, 100, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150),7])
# [1]  46  47  48  49  50  96  97  98  99 100 146 147 148 149 150

print(df[c(46, 47, 48, 49,  50,  96,  97,  98,  99, 100, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150),7])
# [1] NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    "CBA" "CBA" "CBA" "CBA" "CBA"
```

Comment: I cleaned up your example code a bit. Since you weren't using any of the columns in the `iris` data set, it seems pointless to attach your data to `iris`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is due to R's "recycling". As usual, it's much easier to see with a smaller example - let's do 15 rows instead of 150, and we'll run each component separately to see what's going on:

```
## nice small sample
df <- data.frame(
  var1 = 1:15,
  var2 = c(rep(NA, 10), rep("ABC", 4), rep("CBA", 1))
)  

## here's the non-missing var2 values, there are 5 of them
df$var2[!is.na(df$var2)]
# [1] "ABC" "ABC" "ABC" "ABC" "CBA"

## and when we grep them, we get 5 TRUE/FALSE values
(!grepl(exp, df$var2[!is.na(df$var2)], fixed=T))
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

## but how long is var1? 15, not 5
df$var1
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15

## what happens when we index a length-15 vector by less than
## 15 TRUE/FALSE values? The smaller vector is "recycled", that
## is, repeated until it gets to the length of the larger vector.
## Here's a couple examples of that with a length-3 index
df$var1[c(T, F, F)]
# [1]  1  4  7 10 13
df$var1[c(F, T, F)]
# [1]  2  5  8 11 14
df$var1[c(T, T, F)]
# [1]  1  2  4  5  7  8 10 11 13 14

## Remember that your grepl result is length 5
!grepl(exp, df$var2[!is.na(df$var2)], fixed=T)
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

## So it will be recycled 3 times up to length 15,
## and hopefully now this result makes sense!
df$var1[!grepl(exp, df$var2[!is.na(df$var2)], fixed=T)]
# [1]  5 10 15
```

I don't think there's a great way to get the right answer with this subset approach - your first approach with `&` is correct and proper.

Answer (score 1):

`regexpr()` returns `NA`s if it is supplied `NA`s.
If you want elements that **don't match** your expression you can do:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  var1 = 1:150,
  var2 = c(rep(NA, 100), rep("ABC", 45), rep("CBA", 5))
)  

exp <- "BC"
df[regexpr(exp, df$var2, fixed = TRUE) %in% -1, ]
#>     var1 var2
#> 146  146  CBA
#> 147  147  CBA
#> 148  148  CBA
#> 149  149  CBA
#> 150  150  CBA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

`regexpr()` returns -1 when it can't match the expression, `NA` if given `NA` or the position at which it finds the matching expression.
If you wanted the elements that **do** match

```
!(regexpr(exp, df$var2, fixed = TRUE) %in% c(NA, -1))
```

would give all matched and non-missing elements.

Comment: Thank you! I tried `df$var1[regexpr(exp, df$var2, fixed = TRUE) %in% -1]` and it also works fine.